# How to correctly use streams to retrieve, edit, save and send image via discordbot

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I am writing a discord bot using DSharp plus library.

The command I am currently writing gets an image from the discord chat I then edit the image and send the edited image back as a single frame gif.

I retrieve the image from the image url by using:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(attachments[0].Url);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream));
```

I then call my edit function and edit the image. I then save the image to my files using:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("Images/output.gif", FileMode.Create))
{
   imgToGif.SaveAsGif(stream);
}
```

where `.SaveAsGif()` is a function from the KGySoft.Drawing library I found online.

To send the edited image back I use:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("Images/output.gif", FileMode.Open);

DiscordMessageBuilder messagefile = new DiscordMessageBuilder();

messagefile.AddFile(file);

ctx.RespondAsync(messagefile);
```

But this throws a "The process cannot access the file "Image/output.gif" because it is being used by another process." error.

After some googling I tried to close the FileStream which saves my image to my files using `stream.close() or stream.dispose()`. The problem however is that I cannot acces the stream again because it will throw the "Cannot acces closed stream error".

I also tried using `FileShare.read, FileShare.ReadWrite`.

Tried closing both stream and tried to use 1 stream only. So I kept the stream open and used it to send the message in discord chat but that would send a file with 0 bytes in the discord chat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you closed the stream too early while sending the gif

you need to call `file.Close()` after you call `RespondAsync()` and you need to change `ctx.RespondAsync(messagefile);` to `await ctx.RespondAsync(messagefile);` because `RespondAsync()` is an asynchronous method if you dont use `await` rest of the code will continue running so the stream will close while `ctx.RespondAsync(messagefile);` is still running and it will give an error.

sending a gif part should look like this:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("Images/output.gif", FileMode.Open);
DiscordMessageBuilder messagefile = new DiscordMessageBuilder();
messagefile.AddFile(file);
await ctx.RespondAsync(messagefile);
file.Close();
```

if you have done the rest of the code correct this should work.